# Critical gzip mistake - how to undo 'gzip -r ./'

Tags: linux, gzip, gz

So I tried to make a gzipped backup of my entire directory structure, but I inadvertently issued the command `gzip -r ./`, hoping to add all files and folders to a single gzip archive.

This obviously is very wrong, but before I had time to quit, it gzipped each of my files individually (recursively) and deleted the original. Now I have a file structure that is completely made up of gzipped files. Does anyone know the command to undo what I have done (ie. extract the gzip file in place and then delete the gzip file)?

Edit:  Credit to Greg, `gunzip -r ./'` solved it!

Comment: this is probably close: `find -type f -name '*.gz' | xargs gunzip`

Comment: Did you try `gunzip -r ./`?

Comment: Heh. But make sure to *make a backup copy first* this time. It's generally harder to undo an undo gone oops than the initial oops.

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer, since it solved your problem.

Comment: In the future, if you want to make a gzipped backup of your entire filesystem, use `tar czf backup.tar.gz /`.

Answer (score 12):

To undo this, use the opposite command:

```
gunzip -r ./
```

Note that the original `gzip` command will *skip over* files that already have a `.gz` suffix, because there's no point in compressing them twice. However, the above `gunzip` command will *decompress* such files, because it doesn't know that `gzip` skipped them.

Comment: Good point - that might be an argument for using the find idea with -cmin (or -ctime if it's been days ago) as an additional qualifier so as to avoid unzipping what originally were gz files at the time of the accidental command.